# Insert an element with a static value into a flat array of ascending integers when there is an increase of more than 1 between values

Tags: php, arrays, sequential, array-splice, gaps-in-data

I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 10
    [4] => 11
    [5] => 12
    [6] => 13
    [7] => 14
    [8] => 23
    [9] => 24
    [10] => 25
)
```

And I want to fill the gaps so it looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => xxx
    [4] => 10
    [5] => 11
    [6] => 12
    [7] => 13
    [8] => 14
    [9] => xxx
    [10] => 23
    [11] => 24
    [12] => 25
)
```

If you look at the values of the first array, there is `1,2,3` and then a gap and then `10,11,12,13,14` and then a gap and then `23,24,25`. How can I programmatically find these gaps and add a new array element in its place?

There will be a maximum of two gaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `for` loop, without copying the array, but only altering the original:

```
$repl = 'xxx';

for ($i=1; $i<count($array); $i++) {
    $valueR = $array[$i];
    $valueL = $array[$i-1] === $repl ? $array[$i-2] : $array[$i-1];
    if ($valueR > $valueL + 1) {
        array_splice($array, $i++, 0, $repl);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = array();
if (count($oldArray) > 0)
{
    $result[] = $oldArray[0];
    for ($i=1; $i<count($oldArray); $i++)
    {
         if ($oldArray[$i]-$oldArray[$i-1] != 1)
             $result[] =  "xxx";
         $result[] = $oldArray[$i];
    }
}
```

Comment: This removes some of the original array elements.

Comment: @Hasan Khan: You have two syntax errors in there (missing `$`). And I don't understand how `count($result)` can be greater than 0 at this point.

Comment: @netcoder thanks for pointing out. Answer was rushed. Fixed it.

Comment: Now that there is no rush to answer, please [edit] this answer to explain how it works and why you recommend it over other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this, not tested but should work :)

```
$oldArray = array(1,2,3,10,11,12,13,24,25,26,27);

$newArray = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($oldArray);$i++){
    $newArray[] = $oldArray[$i];
    if($oldArray[$i+1] - $oldArray[$i] != 1 && $i+1 != count($oldArray))
        $newArray[] = "xxx"; // seperator
}

var_dump($newArray);
```

Shai

Comment: This seems to add an extra xxx onto the end of the array?

Comment: Check the updated code, added a check to make sure this isn't the last item.

Comment: `Warning: Undefined array key` https://3v4l.org/ptWcu

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doubling the memory by populating a new, extended array, I'll modify the input array (as @netcoder did).

`foreach()` is unsuitable to use with `array_splice()` because will foul up the indexes while you iterate.

For stability, use a `for()` loop.  To minimize calls of `count()`, only call it once at the start of the loop, then bump the cached count only when necessary.

Because the first element will never qualify for the injection of the new element, start the loop at index `1`.

If the the previous element's value + 1 is equal to the current element's value, then inject the element at that position into the original array.  After the injection, bump the `$i` and `$count` variables so that the loop performs an additional iteration, but doesn't bother visiting the injected element.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/YY93f))

```
$array = [-5, 1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 23, 24, 25, 31];
for ($i = 1, $count = count($array); $i < $count; ++$i) {
    if (($array[$i - 1] + 1) != $array[$i]) {
        array_splice($array, $i++, 0, 'xxx');
        ++$count;
    }
}
var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => -5,
  1 => 'xxx',
  2 => 1,
  3 => 2,
  4 => 3,
  5 => 'xxx',
  6 => 10,
  7 => 11,
  8 => 12,
  9 => 13,
  10 => 14,
  11 => 'xxx',
  12 => 23,
  13 => 24,
  14 => 25,
  15 => 'xxx',
  16 => 31,
)
```