# php find gaps and build an array

Tags: php, intervals, sub-array, gaps-in-data

I have this

```
array
    (
        [0] => 1976,
        [1] => 1977,
        [2] => 1978,
        [3] => 1979,
        [4] => 1980,
        [5] => 1981,
        [6] => 1982,
        [7] => 1983,
        [8] => 1990,
        [9] => 1991,
        [10] => 1993,
        [11] => 1994,
        [12] => 1995
    )
```

And i want to find the interval between gaps so it looks like this:

```
$tmp[1]= [[0] => 1976, [1] => 1983]

$tmp[1]= [[0] => 1990, [1] => 1991]

$tmp[1]= [[0] => 1993, [1] => 1995]
```

Eventually I'll be using the same method with largest list of number 
andy idea ?

Comment: What are you having trouble with?

Comment: So, is this something you have tried to solve yourself? Or are you just expecting someone to do this for you? Typically you need to show some effort in at least trying it and people can help.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Yes I was trying to solve it by myself

Comment: Well, you should typically include what you have tried and where you think it is failing or what you are having trouble with. This will get you better responses to show an effort. Up to possibly someone just rewriting it or showing you how to do something better/different. See [ask] in the help center, specifically the section on `Help others reproduce the problem`.  I hope I'm not coming off as rude (even the above comment). I'm honestly trying to help.

Comment: @andrewsi  Shouldn't be on hold I saw this post [similar format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901851/find-gaps-in-a-list-of-numbers) before posting my and its almost looks like my. I thinks my point is to get the result using as any way  possible that would work.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the fact that you didn't provide any code, here is something that could work assuming I understood correctly

```php
    function getIntervals($array) {
       $intervals = [];
       $intervalIndex = 0;
       for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
          //If the beginning is not set, set it.
          if (!isset($intervals[$intervalIndex][0])) {
             $intervals[$intervalIndex][0] = $array[$i];
          }
          if ($i != 0) {
             if ($array[$i] == ($array[$i - 1] + 1)) {
                $intervals[$intervalIndex][1] = $array[$i];
             } else {
                $intervalIndex++;
                $intervals[$intervalIndex][0] = $array[$i];
             }
          }
       }
       return $intervals;
    }
```

Here is a usage example with your list:

```php
getIntervals([
    1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983,
    1990, 1991,
    1993, 1994, 1995,
]);
```

and the expected result:

```
array:3 [
  0 => array:2 [
    0 => 1976
    1 => 1983
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    0 => 1990
    1 => 1991
  ]
  2 => array:2 [
    0 => 1993
    1 => 1995
  ]
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! its works like a charm